# Encode password in oracle/sql server database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, encryption

What is simplest way to encode password in Sql server and Oracle database. in MSAccess password column can be encrypted by just changing property input mask = password.

Comment: masking an input field is NOT encryption. it's still plaintext in the background, it's just that each character is DISPLAYED as something else, e.g. `*`.

Comment: The most secure way would be to store the encrypted value and encrypt and decrypt in your presentation layer - if web based.  Something like using this: http://sjclhelpers.codeplex.com/ and store the value in SQL.  IMHO

Answer (score 0):

you can encode by using  HashBytes() function in sql. SQL Server 2005 and later support this.
In mysql you can use sha1() function.
In oracle you can use dbms_crypto.hash() function.

Hope this helps